# Compound B-Tree Index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, indexing, b-tree

I am researching how to implement a b-tree in JavaScript that can support indexing compound fields. Example object:

```
{
    "name": "Jim",
    "age": 14
}
```

A compound index on both "name" and "age" fields would allow fast full matching, prefix matching and range searches on either the "name" field or the "name" AND "age" field.

How would a b-tree index be coded so that the above can be achieved (in JavaScript or pseudo-code)?

An off-the-shelf solution would also be useful but I am primarily interested in the nitty-gritty internals of the solution so a well explained process of indexing and retrieval would be the most useful answer.

Also any books or technical articles on the subject that anyone might be familiar with would help too!

Comment: The important thing is to establish an ordering: how do you compare two of those keys and know which one is "before" the other? Once you decide that, then it's really exactly the same as an ordinary B-Tree.

Comment: Have you looked at the existing B-Tree implementations in Javascript (a simple Google search reveals plenty of code to look at)?  What are those implementations missing that you want help with?

Comment: @jfriend00 You would hope that everyone uses a search and checks existing libraries first... is there anyone that doesn't do that?!? None of the existing libraries discuss how to use the b-tree to index compound fields in the way I have described above as they are primarily only interested in the insular operation of the b-tree itself, rather than its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make two B-Trees, one that only indexes on name, and another that indexes on name and then age. Now make an interface that allows for lookup in either tree, and offer insertion/deletion methods that do it in both trees to keep them in sync.

Comment: Wow, that is obviously a very simple and effective way to handle this... I was so focused on a single tree that I didn't even think of this. Thanks, I think that will solve it completely.